# Baking Removes My Texture And Replaces It With DarkBlue

Tags: materials, texture-baking, baking

I Get the F.B.X right but Cant Get The right Texture. Baking Works Wrong. I've tried diffuse and combined too

[image: what i want]x5.jpg

[image: error]

Comment: to Bake you need unwrapped whole mesh and each material has to consist from same texture node selected https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168511/2214

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 2.8 - How to bake an ambient occlusion map to a second UV texture on a multi material mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168496/blender-2-8-how-to-bake-an-ambient-occlusion-map-to-a-second-uv-texture-on-a-m)