# How can I go about optimizing textures?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, texture-painting, optimization

I've modeled six rocks, unwrapped all six of them in one texture, but after painting three rocks I decided to reuse them for the remaining three. Is there a way to move these UV islands around along with the textures so that it's more compact?

[image: Cluttered unoptimized textures on the left, final model on the right]

Comment: You can do this by making a second UV map and baking from the old one to the new. This is the closest existing answer I could find for what you need to do https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168496/blender-2-8-how-to-bake-an-ambient-occlusion-map-to-a-second-uv-texture-on-a-m except that you are obviously baking diffuse instead of AO