# How do I texture bake an object with multiple materials on it?

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking

I was trying to make a flashlight object in blender 3.0 earlier, and when I created the materials for it I just assigned them to specific faces on the object. I want to put this object into Unity, though, and I cant figure out how to bake the object correctly with it having multiple materials. For reference this is the object I created: [image: Flashlight]

However When I try to bake it using the methods I usually use it ends up giving me something wonky and unexpected and even when I try to bake just one piece of it something seems to be going wrong.

How should I correctly bake this object to get all the colors in the right spots?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168511/2214 ... you would have to switch pass types and bake them individually (or I thing there was an $ addon to automate baking passes) ... around was better link to Q/A, but I can't find it.

Comment: Here quite nice summary of adding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkBzStwKWao (links in video description)

Comment: There's another detailed one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wG6ON8wZYLc) which was posted on YT two days ago.